# Valgrind doesn't like my realloc()?

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, heap-memory, realloc

```
uint32_t * newArr = realloc( myStruct->arr, 2 * muStruct->Capacity * sizeof(myStruct->arr) )

if (newArr == null)
{
    free(myStruct->arr);
    return false;
}
else
{
    myStruct->arr = newArr;
    myStruct->Capacity *= 2;
    ...
```

Valgrind says about this:

```
Address 0x51f7c80 is 0 bytes after a block size of 80 alloc'd
    at 0x4C2BB78: realloc (vg_replace malloc.c:785)
```

What's going on here? Is it my newArr == null case?

Comment: It is not complaining about `realloc`, but something later in the code.

Comment: The fragment you've presented of valgrind's output is not a complaint about your `realloc()` call.  It's merely an informational addendum to its report about an access violation.

Comment: `sizeof(myStruct->arr)` is the size of the pointer, not of the type it is pointing *to*.

Comment: ... therefore you might not be allocating as much memory as you intended, and subsequently write outside the allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are somewhere reading (or writing) beyond the bounds of an array, as explained in this [valgrind article concerning debugging of memory problems](http://valgrind.org/gallery/linux_mag.html):

> sample2.c: As you can see from the output in Figure Two, references to
>   element 513 in the two arrays cause a write error, a read error, and
>   another write error. The message Address 0x40CA0224 is 0 bytes after a
>   block of size 512 alloc'd indicates that there is no storage beyond
>   the end of the array of 512 bytes.

This is probably somewhere else in your program. Statement `if (newArr == null) ... free(myStruct->arr)` is correct IMHO.